# Bounds with multiple types

Tags: generics, rust

Currently I have the following rust function:

```rust
fn out_cubic(t: f32, begin: f32, change: f32, duration: f32) -> f32 {
    return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
}
```

I'm trying to make both `begin` and `change` parameters generic types. As far I understand, I could use Rust's bounds to say to the compiler that `change` and `begin` should implement the add and multiply operation:

```rust
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

fn out_cubic<T: Add + Mul>(t: f32, begin: T, change: T, duration: f32) -> T {
    return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
}
```

But the above code show the following errors:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/easing.rs:44:21
   |
43 | fn out_cubic<T: Add + Mul>(t: f32, begin: T, change: T, duration: f32) -> T {
   |              - this type parameter
44 |     return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `f32`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                        found type `f32`

error[E0369]: cannot add `T` to `<T as Mul>::Output`
  --> src/easing.rs:44:66
   |
44 |     return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
   |            ----------------------------------------------------- ^ ----- T
   |            |
   |            <T as Mul>::Output
```

Which makes sense, the compiler does not have any way to know that the type `T` should be able to add and multiply with a `f32` type.

My question is, is it possible to create a function that implements both add and multiply operations with `T` and `f32` types? Something like this:

```rust
fn out_cubic<T: Add<T> + Add<f32> + Mul<T> + Mul<f32>>(t: f32, begin: T, change: T, duration: f32) -> T {
    return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
}
```

Comment: What kind of types are you trying to support? Attempting to support arbitrary types will probably end up needlessly complicated, and you'll have issues with calling `f32::powf` and constants such as 1.0 or 3.0. If you just want to be able to send integers to the function, perhaps you should consider a bound of `T: Into<f32>`?

Comment: @user4815162342, I'm trying to support `f32` and vectors ([glam's](https://github.com/bitshifter/glam-rs) `Vec2` , `Vec3`, etc). I can see your point that the code can get complicated, maybe a more naive approach is better for code readability, but I'm also curious about how one would implement this generic case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're adding `f32 + T`, you actually need to assert that `f32` is `Add<T>`:

```rust
fn out_cubic<T>(t: f32, begin: T, change: T, duration: f32) -> T
where
    T: Add<T, Output = T> + Mul<f32, Output = T>, // assert that Output is T
    f32: Add<T> + Add, // the `+ Add` is necessary for f32 to f32 addition for whatever reason
{
    return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
}
```

You could of course, make it even more generic by only asserting that it has to operate on their outputs, but it starts ot get messy:

```rust
fn out_cubic<T>(t: f32, begin: T, change: T, duration: f32) -> <<T as Mul<f32>>::Output as Add<T>>::Output
where
    T: Mul<f32>,
    <T as Mul<f32>>::Output: Add<T>,
    f32: Add<T> + Add,
{
    return change * (f32::powf((t / duration) - 1.0, 3.0) + 1.0) + begin;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but seeing my implementation I don't need (and can't support) the add operation `T + f32`, so removing the `f32: Add<T> + Add,` from the first snippet works correctly.

Comment: I wonder if the remark "the `+ Add` is necessary for f32 to f32 addition for whatever reason" should be reported as a potential compiler issue? It's weird to have to specify a trait bound to get addition on a concrete type that supports it.